# different results in bing chat console and pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, openai-api, bing

when I run this code in pycharm, I get different results than when it is run in bing chat.

in pycharm I get

[['abc'], ['a', 'bc'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

but in bing chat I get

[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'bc'], ['ab', 'c'], ['abc']]

```
My pycharm interpreter(3.11) and decoding(utf-8) are the same as the bing chat.
```

the code is

```
def get_all_sublists(char_list):
    if not char_list:
        return [[]]
    rest = get_all_sublists(char_list[1:])
    result = rest + [[char_list[0]] + x for x in rest]
    return result

char_list = ["a","b","c","ab","bc","abc"]
all_sublists = get_all_sublists(char_list)
matching_sublists = [x for x in all_sublists if ''.join(x) == char_list[-1]]
print(matching_sublists)
```

Comment: The difference in the results is due to the order of the sublists in the rest variable. The get_all_sublists function uses recursion to split the list into two parts: the first element and the rest of the list.

In PyCharm, the recursion is implemented using a stack, which means that the last sublist added to the result is the first one to be returned.  

In Bing chat, the recursion is implemented using a queue, which means that the first sublist added to the result is the first one to be returned.

Comment: Given that the lists contain the same elements bit in a different order, is there a question here?

Comment: thanks guys, I feel like there should be an easy fix here, but I just don't know what that is

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the results is due to the order of the sublists in the rest variable. The get_all_sublists function uses recursion to split the list into two parts: the first element and the rest of the list. It then calls itself on the rest of the list and adds the first element to each sublist in the result. The order of the sublists in the result depends on how the recursion is implemented.

In PyCharm, the recursion is implemented using a stack, which means that the last sublist added to the result is the first one to be returned. This results in a reversed order of the sublists in the rest variable. For example, when char_list is ["a","b","c"], the rest variable is [[], ['c'], ['b'], ['b', 'c'], ['a'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]. This explains why you get [['abc'], ['a', 'bc'], ['a', 'b', 'c']] as the output.

In Bing chat, the recursion is implemented using a queue, which means that the first sublist added to the result is the first one to be returned. This results in a preserved order of the sublists in the rest variable. For example, when char_list is ["a","b","c"], the rest variable is [[], ['a'], ['b'], ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]. This explains why you get [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'bc'], ['ab', 'c'], ['abc']] as the output.

Comment: Thanks Raheel for the great answer, I am not a programmer, is there a way around this? I want the result given by queue recursion, how can I make pycharm to use this recursion instead of stack? thanks again

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t think you can make PyCharm use queue recursion instead of stack recursion. PyCharm is an integrated development environment (IDE) for Python, and Python uses stack recursion by default.

One possible way to simulate queue recursion in Python is to use a deque from the collections module as an auxiliary data structure. A deque is a double-ended queue that allows fast insertion and deletion from both ends. You can use the append() and popleft() methods to enqueue and dequeue elements from the deque.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response and the tips, I will try these or some other ways. great help